# Как сверстать для лендинга такой элемент?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сверху идет секция с градиентным фоном. Снизу эту секцию нужно сделать в форме волны. Как это сделать с помощью html + css. Или же другими способами? Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: svg или изображением

Answer (score 2):

svg, можно и на css сделать, но будет не легко)

```css
.hero-gradient {
  position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: -30px;
     padding: 60px 12px 40px;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(272deg,#4BE074 9%,#10A799 84%);
     background: linear-gradient(-182deg,#4BE074 9%,#10A799 84%);
     height: 400px;
 }
 #wave {
  position: absolute;
     height: 600px;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
 
 svg path {
     fill: #FAFAFA;
 }
 
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  svg {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
     transform: scale(1.2);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-gradient">
 <div id="wave">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1170 193">
   <path d="M1175 131.2c0 0-81-89.4-224.3-103.4S713 72 665 97c-86 46-148 63-271 7C221.7 25.5 56 104.5-4 197.4 -4 58.7-3.3 0.3-3.3 0.3L1175 0V131.2z"></path>
  </svg>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Опробую завтра! 
Вопрос в догонку - а где берете svg path? Вот почему то уверен на 99.9% что рисуется руками, а потом код на выходе дается! Спасибо!